# Rendering Image and Exported image not rendering correctly

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency, effects

So I'm trying to render/export a 3d pixel art with effect on it through the Eevee engine. It shows up correctly on the render preview but when I look at the exported image, it shows up completely transparent. Here's and image of the issue. the Left is the render preview and the right is the actual render.

I've tried changing the blending mode to Alpha Hashed and Alpha Clip but I want the effect of Alpha Blend. The Alpha Hashed and Alpha Clip both have the energy around the rock show up in dots. Any help would be greatly appreciative!

[image]

Comment: PNG is a worthless format that cannot encode pictures with encoded alpha correctly. Blender broke its 8 bit handling to support that format, and completely cannot encode an 8 bit file  to properly support alpha as a result.

Comment: @troy_s I don't see how that helps the question be answered though... :) That looks like a rant which is not really helping anyone. Unless your answer is to use another file format, in which case maybe a pointer in the right direction would be helpful. Cheers

Comment: If the solution is *not use PNG* and that *Blender is busted for 8 bit output*, what exactly would I be able to add? Blender is busted due to PNG and poor design. Use EXR at half or higher. There are no other options.